# Javascript Integer object is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a stored number in the device's memory and parse it to integer using the method `Integer.parseInt`.

```
win:function(){
    this.reset();
    if(Integer.parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("curLevel"))<this.levelNo)
    {
        window.localStorage.setItem("curLevel", this.levelNo+1);
        renderAllLevels();
    }
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#winlevel");
}
```

But when the function `win` is called I recieve the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Integer is not defined`.

I used `Integer.parseInt` in other lines in my project and it worked without any error.

What is the potential error in using it here?

Comment: `parseInt` is a global function. There's no global object called `Integer`. If it wasn't causing errors before, it was probably in a different language.

Comment: When using the `<` comparison you don't really have to parse it, if one side is a number, the other is treated as a number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java != JavaScript.

Use `parseInt(value, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt() is a global method, no need to link it to any object, you might want to change your code like so:

```
if( parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("curLevel")) < this.levelNo )
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `< this.levelNo` part.